# Update column by removing text in braces

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to update single column for all the rows in a table. The update should happen in such way that data needs be filtered out by removing all text where braces are appended for the string and swap the strings separated by `','`.

Example:

```
Column A
---------
Ab,cde(123)
Ab,cde
yz,kol
yz,kol(567)
uv,xyz
first name,lastname (123456)
```

As per the above example, I need the final data to be something like this

```
Output
---------
cde, Ab
cde, Ab
kol, yz
kol, yz
xyz,uv
lastname,first name
```

Please let me know how we can achieve the above output in SQL Server.

Comment: is it always 2 string separated by comma ? Have you tried using `charindex()` and `substring()` to extract the 2 string ?

Comment: Mostly its 2 strings. I need to swap the strings as well after removing the braces and trying to update all the data for column .

Comment: You need to also show us how it works when it is not 2 strings

Comment: Please _stop_ storing CSV data like this.  Just normalize your table and avoid costly string manipulations.

Comment: actually, this is loaded from an excel file. now we stopped loading the excel file and need to cleanse the old data.

Comment: Below query works for your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL Code:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ColumnA AS [Column1]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN charindex('(', ColumnA) > 0
                AND charindex(')', ColumnA) > charindex('(', ColumnA)
                THEN stuff(ColumnA, charindex('(', ColumnA), charindex(')', ColumnA) - charindex('(', ColumnA) + 1, '')
            ELSE ColumnA
            END AS [Column2]
        ,0 AS [Level] FROM t1

    )
    ,cte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY [Level] DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT Column1, Column2 , 
REPLACE( REPLACE(cte1.Column2 , SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2)) , N'')  , N',' , N'') + N', ' + SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2)) AS OutPut
FROM cte1 where Rn = 1
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Nice set-based solution but you are doing a lot more work than is necessary.

Comment: Note too, that this fails when there are duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather easy if you understand how to [Cascade APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-cascading-cross-apply-2) correctly. Note the sample data and solution.

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (ColA VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @table VALUES ('Ab,cde(123)'),('Ab,cde'),('yz,kol'),('yz,kol(567)'),('uv,xyz');

--==== Solution
SELECT 
  [Output] = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(f.String,f2.Pos+1,8000),', ',SUBSTRING(f.String,1,f2.Pos-1))
FROM        @table                                                          AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(',t.ColA),0),LEN(t.ColA)+1))) AS st(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.ColA,1,st.Pos-1)))                          AS f(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String)))                               AS f2(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
Output
-----------------------
cde, Ab
cde, Ab
kol, yz
kol, yz
xyz, uv
```

**UPDATED 20210716**

For those who are wondering why this solution is so much faster, it has to do with the magic of [APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1), [Cascading APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-cascading-cross-apply-2) in this case.
First let's run the queries and compare execution plans:

[image]

The APPLY solution requires a single scalar operator to get the job done. The other way requires a segment and sequence operator to produce the ROW_NUMBER which is sorted and filtered.
Note that 26% of the % in the plan is going to the table variable.

**Performance Test:**

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @table TABLE (ColA VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @table VALUES ('Ab,cde(123)'),('Ab,cde'),('yz,kol'),('yz,kol(567)'),('uv,xyz');

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t.ColA AS [Column1]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN charindex('(', t.ColA) > 0
                AND charindex(')', t.ColA) > charindex('(', t.ColA)
                THEN stuff(t.ColA, charindex('(', t.ColA), charindex(')', t.ColA) - charindex('(', t.ColA) + 1, '')
            ELSE t.ColA
            END AS [Column2]
        ,0 AS [Level] FROM @table AS t
    )
    ,cte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY [Level] DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT Column1, Column2 , 
REPLACE( REPLACE(cte1.Column2 , SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2)) , N'')  , N',' , N'') + N', ' + SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2)) AS OutPut
FROM cte1 where Rn = 1

SELECT 
  [Output] = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(f.String,f2.Pos+1,8000),', ',SUBSTRING(f.String,1,f2.Pos-1))
FROM        @table                                                          AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(',t.ColA),0),LEN(t.ColA)+1))) AS st(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.ColA,1,st.Pos-1)))                          AS f(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String)))                               AS f2(Pos);
GO


-- Test Harness;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table;
CREATE TABLE #table (ColA VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #table 
SELECT TOP (1000000) f.X 
FROM   (VALUES(REPLACE(LEFT(NEWID(),12),'-',',')+'(xxx)'),
              (REPLACE(LEFT(NEWID(),12),'-',','))) AS f(X)
CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns AS b;


--==== Run the test
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(100);

SET STATISTICS TIME  ON;
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t.ColA AS [Column1]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN charindex('(', t.ColA) > 0
                AND charindex(')', t.ColA) > charindex('(', t.ColA)
                THEN stuff(t.ColA, charindex('(', t.ColA), charindex(')', t.ColA) - charindex('(', t.ColA) + 1, '')
            ELSE t.ColA
            END AS [Column2]
        ,0 AS [Level] FROM #table AS t
    )
    ,cte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Column1] ORDER BY [Level] DESC
            ) AS Rn
    FROM cte
    )
SELECT @x = 
REPLACE( REPLACE(cte1.Column2 , SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2)) , N'')  , N',' , N'') + N', ' + SUBSTRING(Column2 , 0 ,  CHARINDEX(N',' , Column2))
FROM cte1 
where Rn = 1

SELECT      @x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(f.String,f2.Pos+1,8000),', ',SUBSTRING(f.String,1,f2.Pos-1))
FROM        #table                                                          AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(',t.ColA),0),LEN(t.ColA)+1))) AS st(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.ColA,1,st.Pos-1)))                          AS f(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(',',f.String)))                               AS f2(Pos)

SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
```

**Test Results:**

```
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 3938 ms,  elapsed time = 3935 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 3422 ms,  elapsed time = 3420 ms.
```

A modest 15% improvement, I expected better but, the APPLY solution is clearly faster.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is very bad solution.

Comment: گلی um, why is that?

Comment: Sorry @DaleK my last comment was for گلی. I updated my post to include execution plans and a performance test.

Comment: Great work... nice to see the evidence of what we know to be true :)